# Share data list between unrelated components instantly RxJS Angular

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have an issue with share data via Service and BehavorSubject.
In app components, I have 2 components not related. When I click on main outlet and want to update data list on service and change data on templates of sider components.

** Service **

```
// behaviorSubject needs an initial value.
  private posts: BehaviorSubject<IPost[]> = new BehaviorSubject([]);
  private postList: IPost[] = [];
  public posts$ = this.posts.asObservable();

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.initializePosts();
  }

  initializePosts() {
    this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos').subscribe(
      (data: any) => {
        this.posts.next(data);
      },
      error => {
      }
    );
  }

  addNew(): void {
    console.log('add new');
    this.http
      .get<IPost>('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
      .subscribe(res => {
        console.log('start');
        this.posts.next(this.posts.getValue().concat([res]));
        this.postList.push(res);
        console.log('after');
        console.log(this.posts.getValue().length);
        console.log('end');
      });
  }
```

** Main Components **

```
<button (click)="onClick()">BUTTON</button>
```

```
data: string[] = [];

  constructor(private mySer: MyService) {}

  ngOnInit() {}

  onClick(): void {
    this.mySer.addNew();
  }
}
```

** Sider Components **

```
{{ posts.length }} - <button (click)="show()">OK</button>
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let value of posts">{{ value.title }}</li>
</ul>
```

```
posts: IPost[] = [];
  subscription: any;
  constructor(private mySr: MyService) {
    mySr.posts$.subscribe((data: any) => (this.posts = data));
  }

  ngOnInit() {}

  show(): void {
    console.log(this.posts.length);
    this.mySr.show();
  }
```

I tested with show function when add more post to BehaviorSubject<IPost[]>. But It don't update in service only work in subscribe.
Please help me and explain that...
Thanks verymuch.

**Stackbliltz** > https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-slzwrj?file=src/app/my.service.ts

Answer (score 1):

first of all advice try to avoid subscription in constructor, beacuse some bindings, like @input bindings, are not initialized and not ready in constructor. i use always ngOnInit to subscribe my observables. but is not this the reason of your error.

in your service you should do:

```js
//from
public posts$ = this.posts.asObservable();

//to
getPosts(): Observable<IPost[]> {
 return this.posts.asObservable();
}
```

then in your component you can subscribe to this function:

```js
posts: IPost[] = [];

constructor(private mySr: MyService) {}

ngOnInit() {
 this.posts = this.mySr.getPosts().subscribe(posts => posts)
}
```

i'm not sure why the first solution dosen't work, i hope someone can explain us better the reason.

Comment: glad to help. if you change your posts$ as i show you your code should work

Answer (score 0):

You can try below solution with Subject.

In your service :

```js
@Injectable()
export class MessageService {
  private readonly _msgUpdated: Subject<any>;

  constructor() {
    this._msgUpdated = new Subject();
  }

  get onMsgUpdated(): Observable<any> {
    return this._msgUpdated.asObservable();
  }  

  sendMessage(msg: any) {
    this._msgUpdated.next(msg);
  }  
}
```

And then when you get the response from api :

```js
this.ApiClient.updateMsg(this.welcomeMsg)
        .subscribe((data) => {
          console.log(data);
          this._msgService.sendMessage(data);          
        });
```

And then you can subscribe to the observable in required component's ngOnInit() method like below:

```js
ngOnInit(): void {        

    this._msgService.onMsgUpdated
      .pipe(takeUntil(this._unsubscribeAll)) //Optional to unsubscribe on Destroy
      .subscribe(msg => {
        if (msg != null) {
          console.log(`message received : ${msg}`);
        }
      });
  }
```

Comment: I tried like it but don't working? What wrong with my code?

Comment: did you see if observable is emitting value ? I would suggest putting log in service to see if 'this._msgUpdated.next(msg);' is getting proper message